# Viewport with external application?

Tags: 3d-view, development

Is it possible to display/draw the viewport of Blender in an another application? eg. Run blender in the background to display the wireframe view of a Blender file within another app? (Sorry if this vague, just trying to understand approaches for Blender application integration.)

Comment: Technically yes, but display a wire frame should be easier by parsing data inside `.blend` file and use any kind of mesh rendering method(eg. OpenGL shader, not even heavily custom) to make it display in your application

Comment: Thanks @HikariTW , I'll look into that option.